# xargs: tar: terminated by signal 13

Tags: pipe, tar, xargs

I'm running the following command to copy files from a list given by `git` to an other directory using `tar` to keep the rights.

```
git ls-files -z | xargs -0 tar -c | tar -x -C ~/tmp
```

This seems to work on some repos, but not on mine:

```
xargs: tar: terminated by signal 13
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answering my own question<sup>1</sup>:

Signal 13 is broken pipe: the receiving end stopped reading but we're still piping into the pipe.

My first hint was a problematic file, so let's add the `-t` option to `xargs` so it prints the command:

```
git ls-files -z | xargs -t -0 tar -c | tar -x -C ~/tmp
```

Output:

```
tar -c [long list of files (2994 files)]
tar -c [sightly less long list of files (~700 files)]
```

At this point the problem appears clear: we're piping *two*  tar calls into one, so the pipe is broken (signal 13).

Indeed, reading the `xargs` manual, we can read that:

> The  command line for command is built up until it reaches a system-defined limit (unless the -n and -L options are used). **The specified command will be invoked as many times as necessary to use up the list of input items.**

You can check out `xargs`'s limits with `xargs --show-limits`. xargs generates multiple commands if the arguments length exceeds the systems limits.

As the system limit for the command line is high (at least on my system, it's 131072 bytes which with my files equivalents to ~3000 files), this can be defined as the general case. This means that if the file list fits within the system-defined limit, the initial command works well.

We can reproduce for every case (well, with at least 2 files), by limiting the number of files `xargs` will throw in every call with the `-L` option:

```
git ls-files -z | xargs -L 1 -t -0 tar -c | tar -x -C ~/tmp
```

The solution is actually to drop `xargs` altogether, by using tar's `-T` option, to read the list of files from a file (or `-`, meaning `stdin`):

```
git ls-files -z | tar --null -T - -c | tar -x -C ~/tmp
```

or

```
git ls-files | tar -T - -c | tar -x -C ~/tmp
```

---

<sup>1</sup>: https://discuss.circleci.com/t/local-checkout-fails-using-cli-tar-terminates-with-signal-13/28632/14

Comment: This is a great writeup. Don't forget to mark your answer as the solution :)

Comment: It would be great if you could mention where to find or change the system limit as well, `man xargs` lists a couple of different values, not sure which one is as play here.

Comment: Yep, good point. It's actually not a limit of files but more a limit of maximum command length. Thanks!